# The development at Getting things GNOME is continuing?

Tags: gnome, package-management, application-development

I like [Getting things GNOME (GTG)](http://gtg.fritalk.com/)  application and I want to know if the development on this application is still active. Do you know something about this?

As far as I see from their website the last release was in 04/2010.

Is the development still active ?

Comment: *Do you know some similar applications?*

Should be another question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's still in development they even have a Google summer Of Code roadmap for this year (2011).  [Link to their Google Summer of Code](http://live.gnome.org/gtg/soc2011_IzidorMatusov)

Answer (score 6):

I started to use [Taskwarrior](http://taskwarrior.org/projects/show/taskwarrior/) recently. It's command-line based but super easy to work with. I've tried most other task apps and this is the one I like the best so far.

[image: Taskwarrior screenshot]

On the other hand, the fact that I have tried as many as I have may be a testament to how good I am at GTD.

Comment: Why did you downvote my answer?

Comment: Without noone who downvoted your answer, i can clearly see that it is off topic. What he asked is whether the development is continuing - he didn't ask if you know a good alternative.

Comment: "Do you know some similar applications?" <- This sounds very much like he did.

Comment: i thought that was a secondary question , not his main one

Comment: First answer was a direct answer to his first question. My answer is an answer to his second. I really don't see a problem here.

Comment: I just gave a guess on why someone would downvote your answer. Usually, if the answer is not addressing the main question, it is to be sent as a comment. Anyway, you are taking this too seriously - i'll upvote it and it's like it never happened :D